# smtplib No email being sent and no errors appear

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send a message through smtplib server :

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Product in Stock Alert'
msg['From'] = 'sender'
msg['To'] = 'reciever'
msg.set_content("Hey, {} is now available in stock\n"
                "Check it out soon : {}".format('hamza', 'google.com'))
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login('gmail', 'code')
    smtp.sendmail('sender', 'reciever' ,msg)
```

i run it through the cmd, but nothing appear or happen, i have lesssecureapps on and 2-step verification off in my gmail account.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you authenticating with the email server?

Comment: what do you mean ? i just ran the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **.as_string()** method to msg:

```
smtp.sendmail('sender', 'reciever', msg.as_string())
```

so, code should look like:

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Product in Stock Alert'
msg['From'] = 'sender'
msg['To'] = 'reciever'
msg.set_content("Hey, {} is now available in stock\n"
                "Check it out soon : {}".format('hamza', 'google.com'))
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login('gmail', 'code')
    smtp.sendmail('sender', 'reciever', msg.as_string())
```